# No Console Output

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export, node-modules

I have written a port scanner, however the open ports are not displayed. Instead, the following happens.

```
Enter command: portscanner
Enter host: 127.0.0.1
Enter start port: 1
Enter end port: 3306 
Enter Command:
```

Main.js:

```
//Imports
import readLine from 'readline-sync';
import { portScanner } from "../commands/Portscanner.js";

while(true) {
    let getCommand = readLine.question('Enter Command: ');
    switch(getCommand) {
        default:
            console.log("Try again");
            break;
        case "portscanner":
            let host = readLine.question('Enter host: ');
            let startPort = Number(readLine.question('Enter start Port: '));
            let endPort = Number(readLine.question('Enter end Port: '));
            portScanner(host, startPort, endPort);
            break;
    }
}
```

Portscanner.js:

```
import net from 'net';

function portScanner(host, startPort, endPort) {
    const openPorts = [];
    for (let port = startPort; port <= endPort; port++) {
        const socket = new net.Socket();
        
        socket.connect(port, host, () => {
            openPorts.push(port);
            console.log("Open: " + port);
            socket.end();
        });
        
        socket.on('error', () => {
            socket.destroy();
        });
    }
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Open Ports:");
        console.log(openPorts);
    }, 5000);
}

export {portScanner};
```

I have asked on various Discord servers and ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0):

In general, using `while(true)` is not really a best practice. Yo are looping over the switch statement without waiting for the portscanner function to return. Maybe you want to have a look at callbacks and/or promises to have a better flow. You should definitly use a debugger.